# Music Covers of stotras

Tags: stotra

Is it wrong to do covers of stotras? I see people talk against music covers of some famous stotras. Some of the common ones are trance covers of shiva stotras and rock cover of arigiri nandini and some videos have head banging and other things which some people find disrespectful. Is it just a bunch of people who can't accept it or are these covers actually doing injustice to the purpose of stotras? Is it breaking any hindhu laws?

Comment: If it is not done with devotion then it is wrong. For entertainment you can choose or compose any songs why to involve hymns ?

Comment: Yes , Very important question. I am also intrested to know about this . But I think most of the experts ,pundits will not say yes to this but only in some cases recommend mantras to be fused with classical music only.

Comment: Any strotra is nothing but stuti of a GOD. While listening to or saying any stotra the only purpose should be increase in devotion to the god. It should increase our ashta satvik bhav towards god. The ROCK version will not give any devotee a devotional touch. Hence it is wrong to do covers of Stotras or any song related to GOD. This is what I think.